# Get only numeric part of a column data?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, numbers, charindex

I have a column in my database containing both numeric and alphanumeric characters.
I only want to get the numeric (6 numbers) from the column.

Example of data:

```
TEST_123456_Prod
DB111111P
F222222FN
PROD999999_SCF
```

I want to create a select statement that returns all rows from this column where all but numbers are filtered out.

I´m using SQL Server, so probably Charindex needs to be used, but no idea how.

Answer (score 3):

To strip off all alphanumeric characters you can create a function as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveAlphaCharacters](@InputString VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
  WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@InputString)>0
        SET @InputString = STUFF(@InputString,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@InputString),1,'')     
  RETURN @InputString
END

GO
```

and then use it to get desired result as:

```
select dbo.RemoveAlphaCharacters(databasename)
from T1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3ccd/1)

Answer (score 2):

This will work for all of your examples:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(databasename, 
              PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', databasename), 
              LEN(databasename) - (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(databasename)) + PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', databasename)) + 2)
FROM dbs
```

Here is a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c895/2) with how the code works.